# month and year function combination is not giving expected results in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to delete all the rows that are in the BATCH: May-2014.

```
data out
set INPUT;
if MONTH(BATCH) NE 05 and YEAR(BATCH) NE 2014;
RUN;
```

Data in Batch column is Numeric in the format MONYY5.

```
EX:::: MAR13, APR14, MAY14, FEB14, JAN14, FEB12
```

After I run the code it is deleting all 2014 records instead of deleting MAY and 2014.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're asking for everythign that is neither 2014 nor 05.  You want everything that is not (both 2014 and 05).

```
data out
set INPUT;
if NOT (MONTH(BATCH) eq 05 and YEAR(BATCH) eq 2014);
RUN;
```

Another option if you know it's MONYY:

```
data out
set INPUT;
if vvalue(batch) ne 'MAY14'; *vvalue gives formatted value
RUN;
```

Only works if you're sure it's formatted that way, though.